# CSS - Image caption alignment not working

Tags: html, css

I have a html that looks like this:

```
                <div class="large-4 columns">
                    <div class="promo-box">
                        <a href="#">
                          <img src="/our-projects-sfk.png">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h5><Våre prosjekter</h5>
                            <p>Hver sommer i 20 år har vi gledet familier som har et kreftrammet barn med tre-dagers drømmetur til Kristiansand Dyrepark.</p>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Since I don't know the width of image in advance, I can't set a fixed width for the div and instead need div and caption to take the width of the image.
I have tried everything, setting the `promo-box` to `display: inline-block` and also setting it to `display: table` and using `figure` and `figcaption` tags, but nothing worked. Not sure how can I set the `caption` to the width of the image?

This is was my attempt:

```
.promo-box {
  display: table;
}

.promo-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.promo-box .caption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

With this the end result was this:

[image]

Comment: Can you make this a full, working example and add some css?

Comment: You're missing a quotation mark on the image.

Comment: We don't need the PHP; post the rendered HTML.

Comment: Maybe `text-align: justify;`?

Answer (score 1):

If your `.promo-box` is a table, you should make the image and the caption container table-rows, and assign `text-align: center` to the caption container.

Addition:

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNyQGQ

I also added a fixed with to the container - otherwise the image will always become as wide as the caption text.

ADDITION AFTER COMMENT:

Okay, then erase the width on the container and change the CSS of the caption to this:

```
.promo-box .caption {
  display: table-caption; /* changed */
  width: 100%; /* changed */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See new codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxMwBK

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the promo-box is set to fixed width, and I need it to take the width of the image, so that the image is always 100% it's natural width, and not stretched to 300px

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Comment: in your codepen the text is also not taking the full width of the image, it looks the same as the example I have in my question

Comment: aha - I am using Firefox, where it looks as desired, but after reading your comment I checked other browsers (Safari and Chrome) and regarding these you are right. Sorry about that....

Answer (score 0):

You want the text to be the same width as the image? You have that. You don't need any of the table or table-caption stuff.

Here, `img` and `.caption` have the same full width of `.promo-box`.

```css
.promo-box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}
.promo-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.promo-box .caption {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="large-4 columns">
  <div class="promo-box">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x250">
      <div class="caption">
        <h5><Våre prosjekter</h5>
        <p>Hver sommer i 20 år har vi gledet familier som har et kreftrammet barn med tre-dagers drømmetur til Kristiansand Dyrepark.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, I need the promo box to be wide as image, now it is taking half of the width of ```large-4 columns```width.